# Rstudio blogdown issues creating new site

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to create a website using the `blogdown` package and the [wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic](https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic) theme, but I have problems with the `new_site()` function.
Below is the code with the error message and my `sessionInfo()`:

```
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
library(blogdown)
blogdown::new_site(theme = "wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic")

― Creating your new site
| Installing the theme wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic from github.com
trying URL 'https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic/archive/master.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length unknown
downloaded 8.4 MB

Error in file(name, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(name, "wb") :
  cannot open file 'starter-hugo-academic-master/exampleSite/resources/_gen/images/media/albums/demo/chris-montgomery-smgTvepind4-unsplash_hu3de7c38bc09fe4bb33ec1fc222105033_3160894_0x190_resize_q75_lanczos.jpg': No such file or directory
```

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8.1 x64 (build 9600)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] blogdown_1.6.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bookdown_0.24     ps_1.6.0          prettyunits_1.1.1 crayon_1.4.2     
 [5] withr_2.4.2       rprojroot_2.0.2   R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.12     
 [9] cli_3.1.0         curl_4.3.2        remotes_2.4.1     rstudioapi_0.13  
[13] callr_3.7.0       blob_1.2.2        vctrs_0.3.8       tools_4.1.2      
[17] xfun_0.28.7       compiler_4.1.2    processx_3.5.2    pkgbuild_1.2.0   
[21] knitr_1.36
```

I also attach `traceback()`, maybe it can be useful

```
> traceback()
6: file(name, "wb")
5: untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir)
4: utils::untar(zipfile, exdir = tmpdir)
3: in_dir("themes", {
       url = if (theme_is_url) 
           theme
       else {
           sprintf("https://%s/%s/archive/%s.tar.gz", hostname, 
               theme, branch)
       }
       zipfile = wd_tempfile(basename(url))
       xfun::download_file(url, zipfile, mode = "wb")
       tmpdir = wd_tempfile()
       on.exit(in_dir("themes", unlink(tmpdir, recursive = TRUE)), 
           add = TRUE)
       if (grepl("[.]zip$", zipfile)) {
           files = utils::unzip(zipfile, exdir = tmpdir)
       }
       else {
           utils::untar(zipfile, exdir = tmpdir)
           files = list_files(tmpdir, all.files = TRUE)
       }
       zipdir = dirname(files)
    ...
2: install_theme(theme, theme_example, hostname = hostname)
1: blogdown::new_site(theme = "wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic")
```